# Как сделать такой карусель на swiper

Tags: javascript, html, css, scss, swiper

Как сделать такую верстку через swiper

пример карусель
https://art-tehnik.ru/

скрин
http://joxi.ru/BA0okeETqp0XN2

```
opacity: 0;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

пробовал через css, но не так работает, как в примере сайта

На активном слайде, чтоб текст слева появился, а картинка справа плавно

Answer (score 0):

нашел решение, получается нужно было добавить только атрибут

```
speed: 0
```